# Assembla Perforce wont submit a large number of files

Tags: version-control, perforce, assembla

I have 1000+ files marked for add that I would like to submit using perforce. During the submit everything seems to work fine but after an hour or so into the submit, using the `p4v` client, I get an error saying "unable to connect to server...as user... try reconnecting"

This seems to happen every time I the p4v client to submit. Also tried using the commandline and  get this message after a while into the submit saying "ssl send failed", "cannot find file specified WSAECONNABORT"

I suspect it has to do with SSL: I am currently hosting my perforce server on assembla.com as they wont give me the option to disable SSL. Is this an SSL problem?

How can I go about solving this?
Pretty desperate and grateful for help.

I've tried the following to no avail:

- uninstalling and reinstalling
- downgrading p4v client versions,
- x86 and x64 bit versions of the p4v client
- Ethernet instead of WiFi

> During the submit everything is fine:

[image: during the submit]

> After about an hour I get this error:

[image: Error]

> If I press the "close p4v" button, this pops up:

[image]

> Since `p4v` is giving me all these errors, I try to submit vi
>   commandline but still get error about an hour into the submit saying:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED IT! instead of trying to submit all the files marked for adds in one big chunk, I submitting it in small portions at a time like 300 or so instead of submitting all 1000+ files at a time.

so to recap the solution to this problem is submit in small portions instead of submitting them all at once.

I hope this helps anybody!

Comment: Glad you solved this. Fairly regularly these days, I submit 20-25000 files at a time. A few years back, I found I could not submit even 10000. Turned out to be an under-powered workstation. Upgrading my workstation resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Perforce server is running out of resources. In Perforce, submits are atomic; It either totally works or totally fails. With such a large submit, if the server ran out of memory, or temporary disk space or something, and choked, the submit would fail. As you found, submitting in more manageable chunks doesn't trigger it.